# Multpass docker how auto mount pernament

Tags: docker, multipass

i create machine

```
multipass launch docker --name=test -vvv
```

see folder in host

```
/home/user/multipass/test/
```

is mounted to `/home/ubuntu/test` in machine.

-great but restart ...

and is not still connected.

how to make to this mount is permanent and why is not connected ?

i try make separated environment for app developing, this is correct way ? put editable files outside so can be easy edit with intelj ide